# How to follow edges in a graph represented by a Map in Java 7?

Tags: java, recursion

```
Collection<String> sources = new ArrayList<String>();
        sources.add("a");
        sources.add("c");
        sources.add("x");
        sources.add("a1");
        sources.add("y");

        Collection<String> targets = new ArrayList<String>();
        targets.add("b");

        Collection<String> overAllFieldMaps = new ArrayList<String>();
        overAllFieldMaps.add("a>b");
        overAllFieldMaps.add("c>a");
        overAllFieldMaps.add("x>c");
        overAllFieldMaps.add("a1>x");
        overAllFieldMaps.add("y>c");

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String aFieldMap : overAllFieldMaps) {
            String[] splittedField = aFieldMap.split("\\>");
            String sourceName = splittedField[0];
            String targetName = splittedField[1];
            map.put(sourceName, targetName);
        }



Expected Result:


a -> b

c -> a -> b

x -> c -> a -> b

a1 -> x -> c -> a -> b

y -> c -> a -> b
```

I am trying to achieve the recursion of path among the data available in map. Can anyone help on this?

In simple ,what i am trying to achieve is Connect by Prior / Common Table Expression equivalent in Java.

Comment: Try some programming tutorials/books yourself that would be more useful to you in solving these problems.

Comment: Your code is clear, your question isn't. If I understood your question, everytime you find a source, you want to see if it's a target?

Comment: Some reading on depth-first and/or breadth-first traversal of graphs may be useful.

Comment: @Ashif I updated my answer to reflect a good comment of [@andythomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202009/andy-thomas). Let me know in a comment if you need the code going with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map#containsValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue(java.lang.Object)) to check if your edge is pointed to by something. Then, you modify the value you're looking for.

Example (assuming only one link will point to the next edge):

```
String print = "";
String end = "b";
while (true) {
    if (!map.containsValue(end)) // Checking if we're at the utmost start
        break;                   // if yes we stop iterating and go print the result
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(end)) {          // Find the path that points to our edge
             System.out.println(print);              // Printing what we had before
            print = entry.getKey().concat(" -> " + print); //Preparing the next output
            end = entry.getKey(); // Updating the edge whose source we're looking for
            break;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(print); // Final output
```

**EDIT :** [Andy Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202009/andy-thomas) pointed to me that the question isn't clear on the traverse order: from last to first or from first to last.

In the latter case, you just have to change keys by values: checking if a key is present, then reading its value and placing it as the new key.

Comment: It's unclear from the question whether the traversal is intended to start at a node and continue along the direction of the directed edges, or traverse backwards from a node, or find the path between two nodes. This answer addresses the second case.

Comment: @AndyThomas From the output of the question, it seemed to me that it was the second case, don't you think so?

Comment: I can't tell. You have a decent answer if the graph can only contain linear paths. It's unclear, however, whether the OP intends multiple sources to point to multiple destinations. From the example code, it looks like the intent is that each source can have only one destination. If the former were true, or the latter false, a complete, non-cyclic traversal of all paths from or to a node might be required.

Comment: @AndyThomas The cyclic will cycle forever in my implementation, indeed. But for the multiple origins, this can be fixed with a simple for loop. I guess this falls back on the TO specifications. Thanks for the precisions though.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to work with graphs, you'll probably need to use a graph framework/library. A Map is a simple key/value structure and you won't be able to use it directly to represent a graph.

Moreover, I think you are interested in finding the path between two nodes: there are a lot of theories on that, and certainly a lot of implementation ready to be used. I suggest you to google java graph library.

**EDIT**:

Assuming the graph is small and that you can basically bruteforce it without thinking, you can do that:

```
    String target = "b";
    for(String source : sources) {
        String cursor = source;
        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
        path.append(source);
        while (cursor!=null && !cursor.equals(target)) {
            cursor = map.get(cursor);
            path.append(" -> ").append(cursor);
        }
        if(cursor != null) {
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    }
```

This code is small and certainly not optimal but it gives the result you are looking for.

Comment: The OP shows an implementation of a graph using a Map. Libraries can be helpful, but sometimes you are required to use your own implementation, either for didactic, technical or licensing reasons.

Comment: I can understand that, but here, this looks too simple: with a Map, you cannot have 2 links with the same key. Therefore a node can only have one 'destination' node. That's why it seems too simple to me.

Comment: It's still a graph. If multiple destinations were required, there's an obvious modification to the Map values.